# SQL Server convert string to datetime fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, datetime

I have data like this :

```
+-----+---------+----------+
| id  | name    | expdate  |
+-----+---------+----------+
| 1   | chookies| 02/2015  |
| 2   | snack   | 03/2015  |
| 3   | snack1  | 04/2015  |
+-----+---------+----------+
```

Datatype of `expdate` is `varchar(7)` and I want to known name of cookies where expired date from now to 03/2015.

I tried with this, but get an error :

```
select     
    id, name, 
    convert(datetime, '01/' + expdate, 103) 
from 
    cookies 
where 
    datediff(month, datetime, convert(datetime, '01/' + expdate, 103))
```

Error:

> Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

I am using SQL Server 2005, what am I missing?

Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Comment: check whether any `expdate` column `month` value is greater than `12` like `'13/2015'`

Comment: there's no data greater than 12

Comment: For me it works as it should check this `declare @date varchar(7)='12/2015'`

`select convert(datetime,'01/'+@date,103)`

Comment: yes, NoDisplayName i think you right, something wrong with data expdate, i try use small data it's work, nothing error with converting data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select 
    id, name, expdate 
from 
    cookies 
where 
    convert(datetime, '01/' + expdate, 103) between getdate() 
                                                and convert(datetime, '01/03/2015', 103)
```

There is no need to use `datediff` function, you will just need to check the `expdate` is between the given period.

Also, you are getting this error because the 2nd parameter in the `datediff` function should be a valid date not just a string 'datetime'.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a simple between in the where clause like so:

```
select id,name,convert(datetime,'01/'+expdate,103) 
from cookies 
where convert(datetime,'01/'+expdate,103) between getdate() and convert(datetime,'2015-03-01 00:00:00.000')
```